# Iterating upto 12 decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm supposed to use fixed point iteration to find the value of "pi" upto 12 decimal places.

Given the equation of iteration I know how to write the loop for the iteration.
But how should I find the number of iterations. 
Appreciate your help.

My suggested code is:

```
def ComputePi():
    import math
    x_n = 3 # the initial point is taken as 3
    while () <12:  # This is the place I need help to count the number of decimal places
        x_n = x_n + math.sin(x_n) # The Iteration equation is given

     return x_n
```

Comment: It looks odd. Were you given that exact code to complete or did you write that?

Comment: Well, you *could* measure the difference `abs(x_n - math.pi)` and check if it's less than `0.5e-12`... but it would be rather strange to use `math.pi` in a function that's supposed to calculate pi.

Comment: @HeapOverflow we were given the context. ad I thought about the code (So there might be mistakes)..

Comment: @kaya3 ... actually as we are estimating the value of "pi" we cannot use it in the computation. But in the iteration step, we know that it will eventually converge to "pi".   And the question ask to do the iteration until you have 12 decimal values.